# Getting Node Module Error (Cannot find module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning the Automated tests by using selenium web driver + Javascript and node.js.
Everything is working fine when I ran that script.js from the Visual Studio code terminal(by using node main.js)

**Problem**
I want to schedule this script in the scheduler which automatically tests the login functionality. But when I try to run it from the task scheduler then it gives **Error: Cannot find module**

[image: Error]

Does anybody know how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix Cannot find module errors, install the modules properly by running a npm install command in the appropriate directory as your project's app. ... or delete the node_modules folder and package-lock. json file and re-install it again using the npm install command.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Comment: I have just a script.js file in a directory and there is nothing else package-lock.json files.

Comment: If you are trying to import one local file inside another and passed a wrong path to the require() function you will see this error again.

To fix this error, pass a correct module path to the require() function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It's tested and working fine even with running with cmd. But the same thing is not working with Task Scheduler.